# Is it a bad practice to call a function recursively on error

Tags: python, function, recursion, exception

So I have simple this function which, on error, is called again by itself until it returns without an error.

```
def enter_r_h() -> (float, float):
     try:
         r = float(input("\n--> Enter the radius of the cylinder\n"))
         h = float(input("--> Enter the height of the cylinder\n"))
     except ValueError:
         print("--> Values aren't entered correctly\n")
         return enter_r_h()
     return r, h
```

Is this a poorly written workaround for when the user enters a bad value since theoretically this could cause a stack overflow (is there such a thing in python?) or the RecursionError.

Comment: In a language that implements "tail recursion", this kind of thing becomes a simple "jump" and causes very little overhead.  Python does not, so this is bad practice.  Recursion should be reserved for algorithms that require recursion.  In this case, the iterative solution is smarter.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your input. I will not do these smart workarounds on an actual job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just put it in a while loop so you are not building the stack?  Then you can also count the number of tries and kill the program if the user is ignorant.

On the other hand, you are very unlikely to fill the stack with manually entered attempts.  The user may die of old age before it is full.

Comment: The default stack size is 1000, and it applies to *all* active stack frames, not just stack frames for recursive calls. Filling the stack isn't quite that hard.

Comment: It's not hard but this one requires a failed user input for each recursion - that would take one thick user with a really strong need for the volume of a cylinder.

Comment: That one made me lol very hard. I did it as a recursive function because our professor likes smart workarounds and since it would be really hard to fail the function on this one I thought maybe it can pass as a valid solution.

Comment: You should strive to write code that *does* work, not code that should work if used as intended. Buffer-overflow attacks work because code didn't anticipated worst-case scenarios like this.